# error de un if en una modal de bootstrap porque?

Tags: php, php5, php7

hola buenas noches algo me tiene confundido .. tengo una modal que muestra un boton ... esta relacionado en el id de una publicacion .. la modal si me trae el id porq las acciones de eliminar modificar y publicar funcionan bien.. pero al momento de colcar un if dentro de la modal no funciona  ... la idea es q si el id es 0 no muestre .. si es 1 muestre ...

```js
<?php    if($row['estatus'] == '0'){?>

              <button type="button" id="<?php echo $row['servicio_id'];?>" class="btn btn-outline-info changeServicio" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".MostrarS" name="mostrar">no mostrar</button>


<?php }else{ ?>

<button type="button" id="<?php echo $row['servicio_id'];?>" class="btn btn-outline-info changeServicio" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".MostrarS" name="publicado">Mostrar</button>


<?php } ?>
```

cuando coloco el cod fuera de la modal funciona perfectamente pero dentro de la modal no .. porq pasa esto ?

Comment: quité la etiqueta Java pues claramente aquí no se esta usando dicho elnguaje

Answer (score 0):

No entendi muy bien que es lo que no funciona...La modal o los botones?De todos modos;
Por que mostrarias un boton que diga no mostrar?
Ademas, estas seguro de que la condicion `$row['estatus'] == '0'` no se cumple?

Yo lo que haria seria esto:

```
<?php  if($row['estatus'] == '1'){?>

      <button type="button" id="<?php echo $row['servicio_id'];?>" class="btn btn-outline-info changeServicio" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".MostrarS" name="publicado">Mostrar</button>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: en la modal tengo el boton mostrar.... cuando doy a mostrar y la función se cumple .... el if no hace su  función... osea no me muestra el boton  "no mostrar" para ocultar la publicacion...

Comment: cuando pruebo el cod fuera de la modal  el if si me muestra el boton "no mostrar" pero en la modal nunca sucede